# What is a zero dimensional stochastic system?

Tags: noise, stochastic-processes

I happened to read a statement about Zero-dimensional stochastic systems in the context of Noise-induced phase Transitions (https://doi.org/10.1140/epjb/e2018-80624-9). I am not sure what does a zero-dimensional stochastic system represent. I would really appreciate some clarification on this with some physically relevant examples or applications.

Comment: $\uparrow$ Read where? Which page?

Comment: @Qmechanic I edited the original post to include the reference.

Comment: It just means that there is no space dimension in the equation. Quite often you'd write, for example, $df(x, t) = g(x, t)dt + \sigma(x, t) dW(x, t)$ (and typically, say in a Ginzburg-Landau situation, $g$ would actually be a functional of $f$, depending on t, x, f, and f's derivatives, making the whole thing "nonlocal" in some sense), but when it is zero dimensional, there is no dependence on x.

Comment: @alarge thanks. That explains it to a satisfactory extent.